# How to get the index of an Object without writing a loop javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Have an Object, which has success and error objects in it. Expected answer is, I have an ajax call wrapper, so this wrapper stops the normal behaviour of ajax. once the api gets the response, the response will bypass to my wrapper and there i will take that object and search for the "key", this key will be same to the below object "key"

for example response.key = "01", I need to match this key with my below object. I can do it by using a loop. but i don't want to write a loop, because the response might have thousand of values which will impact the performance. Is there any such a way that I can achieve this without using loops.
help me out with a basic demo example. thanks.

Object:

```
var getValue = {
    success: {
        "01":"success 1",
        "02":"success 2"
    },
    failure: {
        "03":"failure 1",
        "04":"failure 2"
    },
};
```

Comment: *"...i don't want to write a loop, because the response might have thousand of values which will impact the performance"* It's going to require a loop at some level.

Comment: @squint: If that not going to effect the performance then its fine. If you can share me a sample demo, it would be grateful

Comment: I'm confused, if the *..."the key will be the same to the below object "key"* you could just `getValue.success[responseKey]`

Comment: Wait... which part may have a thousand objects? I think you need to give more insight into your actual data.

Comment: @squint: the success and failure object will be having more values in it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "get the index"?

Comment: @M-S: Those aren't objects. Those are properties of objects holding strings. Clearly if you're given the key for one of two objects, then you don't need a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
return getValue.success[response.key]||getValue.failure[response.key];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have "success" and "failure", you could try:

```
    if (getValue.success[response.key]) {
        console.log(getValue.success[response.key]);
    } else {
        console.warn(getValue.failure[response.key]);
    }
```